# Showing that limit of function $f$ equals $0$ if limit of composite equals $0$ given that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, continuity

Suppose $A, B\subset \mathbb R^n$ and that $f:A\to B$ is bijective and continuous. Suppose also that $f^{-1}$ is continuous **(I added this assumption)**.

Fix $d\in B$ and set $b=f^{-1}(d)$.

Now suppose $F:B \to \mathbb R^n$ is a function. Consider $a\in A$. Set $c=f(a)$ so that $a=f^{-1}(c)$

Consider $F\circ f: A\to \mathbb R^n$. I have shown that $\lim_{a\to b}\| (F\circ f)(a)\|=0$.

I want to conclude that $\lim_{c \to d} \| F(c)\|=0$ as well.

It seems as though I could just plug in $a=f^{-1}(c)$ to $F\circ f$  in order to justify this conclusion. But is this a legal move, or is there something I am missing? Do I need continuity?

Comment: I think you can do that

Comment: As long as it's continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the claim is wrong if $f^{-1}$ is not continuous !

Take $A=[0,2\pi) \times \{0\} $ and $B=\text{closed unit circle }$ in $R^2$

Define $f(t,0) = e^{it}$ then $f(0)=(1,0) \in B$ , and take $F=f^{-1}.$

Then $\lim_{a\to 0}(F\circ f)(a)= 0$ but $\lim_{c \to (1,0)} F(c)= \text{does not exist}$!

If $f^{-1}$ is continuous then  the claim is true since, one can check that :

$$x \rightarrow y    \quad \text{if and only if}  \quad f(x) \rightarrow f(y) $$

Comment: What if we know that the inverse must be continuous?

Comment: @Richie519 Then it is true!    if $f^{-1}$ is continuous then $f$ is a homeomorphism so

$$x \rightarrow y    \quad \text{if and only if}  \quad f(x) \rightarrow f(y) $$

Comment: I'm sorry, I understand now. Thank you.